# How to insert composite column as one single column in sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

```
for row in dfp.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO athletes(id, season, name)
                VALUES (?,?,?)
                ''',
                (
                    row.id,
                    row.season,
                    row.name,
                    )
'''

            )
```

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement.

I am getting this error because name is composed of first name and last name, so it is considering it as two different parameters when in reality it is only a single parameter. The same thing is happening in another table when I am using date (considering it as 3 parameters).

Comment: Remove that last triple single quote:`'''`

Comment: yes, it is not part of the code in reality, I just put it for stack overflow to make it appear in code format then forgot to remove. My bad. The problem still lies with the fact that name is being considered as two columns. For instance, if we have "John Smith" as name in first row, we are considering them as two params

Comment: If there are 3 columns in the table and you pass 3 parameters then there should not be an error.

Comment: show the create table and the complete execute code, the error message doesn't fit the code sample

Comment: CREATE TABLE athletes(
    id int,
    season int,
    name varchar(50),
    primary key(id, season))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pymysql, don't use `?` as the parameter placeholders. Use `%s`.

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO athletes(id, season, name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)''',
    (row.id, row.season, row.name,))
```

Comment: Should it be %s for date also?

Comment: Yes, for all data types. When used as a parameter placeholder for pymysql, it is not a formatting control like it is for Python's `format()` or f-strings, it is always `%s` regardless of data type.